# AR.js large model file, is there a way to add loading progress bar?

Tags: three.js, progress-bar, augmented-reality, ar.js

I thought my little web page failed on my iphone until i realize it actually did, just that the model file size is a bit large and it takes sometime to load.

Is it possible to get the percentage of how much the model is loaded and to get a callback when it's completely downloaded? So users know it's downloading and takes some time.

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.9.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/1.6.2/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>

<body style='margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;'>
    <a-scene embedded arjs=''>
        <a-marker preset="hiro">
            <a-entity obj-model="obj: url(obj/render.obj);
            mtl: url(obj/render.mtl)" scale=".005 .005 .005">
            <!--<a-entity fbx-model="src: url(obj/render.fbx);">-->
            </a-entity>
        </a-marker>
            <a-entity camera></a-entity>
    </a-scene>
</body></html>
```